# how to simultaneously update two div using jquery ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am designing a **like and dislike** feature. But problem arise when i update my like as the same time it must update the dislike `div` too.

this is my .js for dislike:

```
$('.dislike').click(function(e) {
    dislike = $(this);
    to_dislike= dislike.data('val');
    $.ajax({
        type     : 'POST',
        url      : '<?php echo site_url('/url.php');?>',
        data     : 'dislikes='+to_dislike,
        dataType : 'text',
        success  : function(data){
            $("#dislike_"+to_dislike).html(data);
        },
        error    : function(){
            $("#dislike_"+to_dislike).html('Sorry');
        }
    });
});
```

Its working good. but i want to modify it in such a way that it should simultaneously update my div:

`<div id='like'></div>`

Here is my HTML :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> <button class="like"></button></td>
        <td> <button class="dislike"></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LIKE : <div id='like'></div></td>
        <td> Dislike : <div id='dislike'></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT:**

Update: I have to fetch data about like and dislike at same time and then put that data in two different div's. There is a table with `like` and `dislike` column.**On like i update my likes. But if a person dislike after liking a particular post then dislike is updated to +1 and like is updated to -1.**

please help..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it should simultaneously update my div", can you provide a reproducible example of your issue? preferably in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: need to be more detailed about what `update` means. Some html would help also

Comment: i have to fetch data about like and dislike at same time and then put that data in two different divs

Comment: what's in your data and how is it structured... last comment doesn't tell us much

Comment: @charlietfl its the number(integer) of like and dislike about perticular post

Comment: ok I have 2 numbers now.... still no idea what the issue is...or how that data is structured. You aren't making this easy for us to understand

Comment: @charlietfl there is a table with like and dislike column. on like i update my likes. But if a person dislike after liking a particular post then dislike is updated to +1 and like is updated to -1. I hope it helped

Comment: ok so what do you need...how to parse the text in table...or just change it with new data? Back to ...a simple html demo would help

Comment: @charlietfl I would like to change both the div's with new data. But with one ajax call.

Comment: isn't the data sent back in call you already make?

Comment: @charlietfl yes, data is sent about that particular post who is to updated

Comment: are you expecting your code to do something in success that it doesn't ?

Comment: @MinaGabriel i want one ajax call and update 2 different div's at success

Comment: Rahul.... I suggest you start all over and provide html and sample data . We have no idea what you need without seeing both

Comment: so you don't have any issue updating your database you are saying that the issue is your success function update the status of one div and not the other ... right ?

Comment: @MinaGabriel Yes dear i have to update my database too.

Comment: I think this is not meant to be, but both your like and dislike divs have the same id (like)

Comment: @Bigood can you give me some idea how can we make this work that way

Comment: You mean, with two divs with the same ID? [You shouldn't!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-types)

Comment: @Bigood no dear dislike are there in div with id="dislike" whereas like are also in div with seperate id="like"

Comment: Ok, so correct your code in your question, and forget about it.

Comment: @Bigood oops that was typo.

Answer (score 2):

If i am getting you right then u want to get data from database and display it in two different div using one jquery call.

Why don't you concatenate the string with some symbol like `$` and then when echo it. On Success just filter the data and put it in different div. Hope it helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you just want to update the number of likes and dislikes in your divs.

```
$('.dislike').click(function(e) {
   dislike = $(this);
   to_dislike= dislike.data('val');
   $.ajax({
       type     : 'POST',
       url      : '<?php echo site_url('/url.php');?>',
       data     : 'dislikes='+to_dislike,
       dataType : 'text',
       success  : function(data){
           var dislike = parseInt($("#dislike").html());
           var like = parseInt($("#like").html());
           if ( dislike >= 0 && like >= 0) {
              $("#dislike").html(dislike + 1);
              $("#like").html(like - 1);
           }
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: I want to update that for sure but want the values to be coming from database.It just showing an updated value not really fetching updated value from database. +1 for trying.

Comment: @Rahul what does the response from your server look like?